# How do I run casper from within the phantomjs shell?

Tags: phantomjs, casperjs

Anyone know if and how it's possible to run casperjs from within the phantomjs shell (a.k.a [InteractiveModeREPL](http://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/wiki/InteractiveModeREPL) )?

[image: phantomjs shell]

I've also tried passing the direct path to the casper.js module and that has not worked either.

**Progress/Update:**

- Tried `phantomjs.injectJs('C:/casperjs/module/casper.js');` but got `Error: Cannot find module 'colorizer'` I guess I'm getting close.
- This gets me closer but still missing path:

  - `phantomjs.injectJs('C:/casperjs/module/bin/bootstrap.js')`

    - errors out with `Cannot find package.json at C:/package.json`
  - OK, looks like I can pass the --casper-path option when starting phantomjs (see - casper/bin/bootstrap.js: line 189).
  - OK that worked. (passing the option did not work but setting the path inside of phantom did).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So to get this stuff to run inside the phantomjs shell  first you need to set a `casperPath` variable in the phantom global object.

`phantom.casperPath = "C:/casper";`

Then you need to inJect caspers's `bootstrap.js` file.

`phantom.injectJs("C:/casper/bin/bootstrap.js");`

Now you can instantiate a casper object and play with it in the shell.

`var casper = require("casper").create();`

enjoy.

Comment: No longer works.  See [casper 1.1 upgrading](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/upgrading/1.1.html) and this [more recent question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19857139/running-casperjs-test-in-phantom).

Comment: It doesn't work for me . phantomjs 1.9.8 no longer has the casperPath varaible.

Comment: Any workaround in 2016 to have interactive mode with casper-1.1.1 and phantomjs 1.9.1 ?