# Running 'casperjs test' in phantom

Tags: node.js, phantomjs, casperjs

So I have a file running in node which runs a local copy of PhantomJS as below shows:

```
phantom.casperPath = 'node_modules/casperjs';
phantom.injectJs('node_modules/casperjs/bin/bootstrap.js');
var casper = require('casper').create({
    viewportSize: config.viewportSize
});

casper.test.begin('Runing tests here', 5, function suite(test) {
    // Tests here
});
```

Without the `casper.test.begin()` my tests function fine. I have the correct version `1.1.0` which can use this test suite but I get the following error in my console:

```
CasperError: casper.test property is only available using the `casperjs test` command
```

The CasperJS docs mentions this too: http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/testing.html. My question is how do I run this Casper under this command in the above code so I can use these tests?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

> CasperError: casper.test property is only available using the `casperjs test` command

problem solved.

You have to include this line at the top of your script in your `xyz.js`, so that the `.test` property becomes true;

```
phantom.casperTest = true;
```

Then you should have no problem Launching from the terminal:

```
casperjs xyz.js
```

Comment: In my reading of bootstrap.js, I see the setting of casperTest, but quite a number of things are done.  This answer was not sufficient in my use case of running capserjs from a phantomjs REPL.

Answer (score 0):

you can also call `casperjs test xyz.js`

For more info, check the doco here : http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/testing.html