# CasperError: Can't find module CasperJS after upgrading to version 1.1.3

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

I am upgrading `casper` from version 1.0.2 to 1.1.3. I also upgraded phantom 1.9.7 to 2.1.1.
My code was working fine with version 1.0.2, but as soon as I upgraded it to higher version, I am getting two error:

- `CasperError: Can't find module ./lib/extended`
- `phantomjs://code/bootstrap.js:297 in patchedRequire`

On this line:

```
var casper = require('./lib/extended').create ()
```

I've tried [this approach](https://github.com/casperjs/casperjs/pull/561), but it didn't worked.

Comment: `require('./extended')` in casper 1.1.13 throw a error, but it worked on 1.0.2, anybody used casper and can help me?"

Comment: Somebody reinstalled CasperJS (and maybe PhantomJS too) and it started to work again. Try to do a clean install. Also, how are you installing it?

Comment: i am using binary, and through changing environmental variable in windows. Many at time i change version, but i have to restart my machine to see the updated version bu phantomjs -v or casperjs --v. But this is something with phantom lib, defining the path. is there any way changing casper path by initiating phantom object in my JS.

Comment: Yes, you can load CasperJS into PhantomJS: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13102134/1816580